# Using a regex variable from within the regex itself, within PHP

Tags: php, regex

> **My goal:** I'm trying to use regex to retrieve a name string from the jumbled response of a `file_get_contents()` call within PHP.

Here's an excerpt of what I get back from a `file_get_contents` call, and the string I will be working with:

```
file_get_contents('http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent');
```

> 28:announce39://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce13:announce-listll39://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announceel44://ipv6.torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announceee7:comment29:Ubuntu CD releases.ubuntu.com13:creation datei1382003607e4:infod6:lengthi925892608e4:**name30:ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso12**:piece lengthi524288e6:pieces35320:I½ÊŒÞJÕ`9

You can see how I've emboldened the text of interest above. The regex I'm using is currently as follows:

```
preg_match('/name[0-9]+\:(.*?)\:/i', $c, $matches);
```

This gives me:

```
name30:ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso12
```

Now, **name30** is the name and also **30 characters** in length from the next semi-colon, so how can I use this variable to continue on for *only 30 characters length* before finishing the regex, whilst removing the "name" string and count characters?

My end goal would be:

```
ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Note: I did think of just removing any end numbers instead of character counting, however the filename may not have a valid extension and may just end with numbers in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `name([0-9]+):` is solid for finding the start of what you need, you could use `preg_replace_callback`

```
$names = array();
preg_replace_callback("/name([0-9]+):(.*?):/i", function($matches) use (&$names){
    // Substring of second group up to the length of the first group
    $names[] = substr($matches[2], 0, $matches[1]);
}, $c);
```

Comment: Nice! No idea who downvoted... Only addition here is to pass `$names` by reference to make it work (`&$names`), but that seems to work perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

An other way:

```
preg_match_all('/:name(\d+):\K[^:]+/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $results[] = substr(match[0], 0, $match[1]);
}
```